# How add own class to WP Nav Menu

Tags: wordpress, submenu

I already know how to add own class to Wordpress Menu or reach parent li of sub-menu by:

```
function my_nav_special_class($classes, $item){
    if(in_array('current-menu-ancestor', $classes)){
        $classes[] = 'my_class';
    }
    return $classes;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'my_nav_special_class' , 10 , 2);
```

but I don't know how to target only sub-menu li items. It would be just great if this class was slug name of item-title, but just simple class will be nice too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use [Walker_Nav_Menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Using_a_Custom_Walker_Function) for that, it is for traversing through all menu items.

$depth - current level of the item ( counts the first level as 0 )

$item - object that holds all data for item

```
// header.php
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary', 'walker' => new my_walker_nav_menu() ) );

// functions.php
class my_walker_nav_menu extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth, $args ) {
        if ( $depth == 1 ) {
            $item->classes[] = 'my_class';
        }
        parent::start_el($output, $item, $depth, $args);  
    }
}
```

The above example adds `my_class` to all sub-menu li items, but this way you can change anything you want.

Comment: I'm sorry for this late reply. Your code works great! Thank You for help :)